# Trying to execute PHP code online but not succeeding

Tags: php, html

I am trying to execute a PHP code online by entering the filepath into the URL of my browser, but what pops up at the bottom of my screen is the message "Do you want to open or save ironcurtain.php?"
When I open it, I simply get the TextPad editor that I'd written the codes in, in the first place. 
A few days ago, I entered the filepath into the URL of Internet Explorer just as I am doing today, and the webpage DID appear. I am doing nothing different today, but the webpage is not appearing today. The PHP code that I am trying to run is given below. (This is actually PART of a longer code, but my question really has nothing to do with the PHP code itself, but WHY I am getting a question which then simply reopens my TextPad). Can anyone tell me if there is a way around this problem? I prefer using IE as opposed to Opera or anything else.

```
      <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","churchill");
        // Check connection
         if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
              ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? When you say "file path" are you trying to run PHP without a server?

Comment: Do you have php installed on your computer? php is a server-side language and requires a "server" to run. If your computer is not configured as a server to run php, then you will get the "download this file" message. If your computer is correctly configured as a server, then you'll be taken to an interpretation of the web page you created.

Comment: Few questions to stretch the possible lists of problems... Are u using xampp or wampp to serve the page? Did you check if Apache service was started? did you put a local file path directly in the browser...?

Comment: Jay, Enigmadan and Sergio, thank you for your replies. The server in question is actually a remote MySQL server that I HAD access to until two days ago and I was able to view my data on a phpMyAdmin. Also, I do have a server because I CAN view my HTML page when I use Opera but I can't when I use IE. Trouble is, Opera does not open my second HTML page. Never mind, I'll use my college's computer and nothing like this ever happens there. Thanks all of you.